# Adding an item programatically in navigation drawer menu

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I have a navigation drawer in my application. I want to add an option programatically in the second section of the navigation drawer's menu. The menu.xml is-

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_connect_sensor"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth"
        android:title="Connect Bluetooth" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_take_tour"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_video"
        android:title="Take a tour" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_my_stats"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_bargraph"
        android:title="My Stats" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_group_title"
    android:id="@+id/other_labels">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_myAccountSettings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="My Account" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_application_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:title="Application Settings" />
        <item android:id="@+id/comparison"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz"
            android:title="Compare"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_help_and_feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_live_help"
            android:title="Help and Feedback" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_exit"
            android:title="Sign Out" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

For adding an option programatically-

```
    Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, Menu.FIRST, "Players")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_people);
```

This option is getting added at the last. How can I add the option in the third position i.e. below Application Settings

Comment: third argument of add() method is order. try this menu.add(0,Menu.FIRST,2,"Players")

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Menu.THIRD=3;

 Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
        menu.add(0, Menu.THIRD, 2, "Players")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.music_audio);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use.

```
Menu menu = navView.getMenu(); // navView is NavigationView reference.
menu.add("Item 1");
menu.add("Item 2");
menu.add("Item 3");
```